# Вопрос по безопасности SQL-запросов

Tags: безопасность, sql, mysql

Всегда обрабатывал строковые переменные в `SQL`-запросах функцией `mysql_real_escape_string()`, числовые - `intval`.
Недавно мне попал в руки скрипт, в котором программист заключает переменные в `SQL`-запросах просто в { }
Например, такой запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts WHERE user_id = {$user} AND folder_id = {$folder}
```

насколько безопасен?
Почему не переменные не обрабатываются `intval`? В этом запросе есть `SQL`-уязвимость?

И ещё несколько вопросов по SQL:
Нужно обрабатывать переменные только пришедшие извне (из `GET POST` и т.д.) или абсолютно все переменные, которые присутствуют в запросе? (Даже те которые устанавливаются в теле скрипта, например `$user_id = 28473`;)

И ещё, есть ли разница и какой вариант лучше выбрать?

1. ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts WHERE user_id = '".intval($user_id)."'
   ```
2. ```
   $user = intval($user_id);
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts WHERE user_id = '".$user."'
   ```

Работаю с БД `MySQL`

Comment: уже давно все`PDO` или `MySQLi` используют и не мучайтесь над этим.

Answer (score 1):

1) Заключение в фигурные скобки (в данном случае) это всего лишь один из способов подстановки переменной в строку, обычно используется для подстановки значения из массива.

Подобная конструкция совершенно никак не обрабатывает переменную, в этом можно убедиться путем простого эксперимента:

```
$user_id = "0 OR 1=1";
echo "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts WHERE user_id = {$user_id}";

//Вывод: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts WHERE user_id = 0 OR 1=1
```

2) Необходимо обрабатывать все переменные, которые будут участвовать в запросе, если есть хотя бы малая вероятность того, что они могут быть некорректны.

3) Объявление лишней переменной оправданно только в том случае, если код от этого станет на много читабельней для дальнейшей поддержки. Во всех остальных случаях - это лишняя память и время на отработку скрипта.

И если есть возможность для данного проекта, посмотрите в сторону PDO.
"The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO."

Критику ответа приветствую.